# Laravel migrate issue

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I just started using laravel v5.4 and I face an error with migration everytime !

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException] SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 

Table 'users' already exists (SQL: create table ` users` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `name`     varchar(255) not null, `email` varch
  ar(255) not null, `password` varchar(255) not null, `remember_token`    varchar(100) null, `created_at` times
  tamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8mb4   collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci)

[PDOException] SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users' already exists
```

I am using xampp with Server version: 10.1.21-MariaDB
I tried everything such as migrate:rollback and migrate:refresh and I tried also to delete the tables and migrate again but nothing happen ! 
Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you run this command line `php artisan make:auth` and now you are trying to create a table named users.There is already a users table in your db.

Comment: if i just try laravel new blog 
then php artisan migrate it will show the same error !

Comment: @HouzayfaRifai Did you empty the database or start with a fresh one, or are you re-using an old database that already has tables in it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the laravel Auth controller you need to create the migration first. This can be done by running:

```
php artisan make:auth
```

You get 2 migrations at `/database/migrations/` and some views in `/resources/views/auth and /layout`

Then verify your database credentials are valid in your `.env` configuration.
Check if the database contains a table called **migrations** if is so, remove it!

If you now execute

```
php artisan migrate
```

All schemas from `/database/migrations/` will be executed.